# Excel Export of SSRS Report shows outdated data

Tags: excel, reporting-services, export

I have an SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) report, that uses a view. That few had to be adjusted yesterday. Now the report shows online the correct data, however as soon as I click on export to Excel it seems to bring to outdated data. Opening the Excel yields data that was correct before the view adjustment. Is this Excel Version somewhere cached ? Or what could explain this strange behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found now that it is related to grouping records, when I have two grouping levels on the report these duplicate rows appear. When I have only one grouping level then it works. So what I assumed is outdated data, was just a coincidence of my view change with a general bug in the excel export. Seems that it is a known bug, however MSFT seems not very eager to ship a fix.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running the report? From the designer. If so, you do get caching issues unless a parameter has changed.

If running from your reporting server check that no versions of EXCEL.exe are running.

Also, is this the same behaviour on all users PC's?

Comment: I run it as a normal user through IE. Several users have the exact same problem. I already tried to modify the report and redeploy it. Didn't help. And I made sure no versions of Excel are running anywhere(server nor client) at the time of the export. Is there any clear documentation how the excel rendering works step by step ?